# Can I pivot dynamic table with no group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is my data in table (left join from field table and value table)

[image]

This is my expected result table after use pivot function

[image]

Thanks for help ^___^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use dynamic SQL as `fieldnames` number may very in future:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns,'') + ',' + QUOTENAME(c.fieldname)
FROM [Columns] c
ORDER BY c.cid

SELECT @sql = N'
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  v.[row],
            c.fieldname,
            v.fieldvalue
    FROM [Values] v
    INNER JOIN [Columns] c
        ON v.cid = c.cid
    ) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(fieldvalue) FOR fieldname IN ('+STUFF(@columns,1,1,'')+')
) pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Will output:

```
row FirstName   LastName    Email               Phone
1   Arnun       Saelim      Arnun.s@outlook.com 0922743838
2   Micheal     Saelim      Micheal@gmail.com   0886195353
```

Comment: this is awesome solution

Comment: My pleasure! :) Great that it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why group by got into your mind, but here is a working example of what you are trying to achieve.

```
    select *  into #temp from   
( values
(1,'A','AV'),
(1,'B','BV'),
(1,'C','CV'),
(2,'A','AV'),
(2,'B','BV'),
(2,'C','CV')) 
as t(row, FieldName, FieldValue)

select * 
from #temp
PIVOT
(MAX(FieldValue) FOR FieldName in ([A],[B],[C])) as pvt
```

Does that work for you?